# Different Docker Version in Windows and Rancher Desktop VM

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, rancher-desktop

I installed Rancher Desktop (no prior Docker install/Docker Desktop install or anything like that) on **Windows 11**. I installed it with the dockerd option, I checked the docker version on Powershell, and I got **24.0.6**; I entered the Rancher Desktop VM (*rdctl shell*) and checked the docker version, and I got **23.0.6**; for docker-compose, I got the same version 2.21.0 both on Powershell and on Rancher Desktop VM (*rdctl shell*).

1. How come I have a different docker version? I would expect the docker version to be the same, wouldn't I?
2. Can I update the docker version provided by Rancher Desktop to the latest version (24.0.7) and docker-compose to the latest version (2.23.0)? And if yes, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered on the official Rancher QA [here](https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/discussions/5856).